# Create Selenium Webdriver once and use in Cucumber's all steps

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, cucumber

I've experience in Back-End automation testing, but I'm new to Front-End.
I've created BDD format tests for a website and now I want to automate it.
I decided to use Selenium + cucumber using Maven for desktop versions of website.

Now let's start:

For example my feature file looks something like this:

```
Feature: User change password page
Scenario: User doesn't provide passwords
Given user is logged in 
And user is on change password page
When user clicks SAVE button
Then website should notify that password fields are mandatory

Scenario: User types wrong current password
Given user is logged in 
And user is on change password page
When user provides invalid current password
And user clicks on save button
Then website should notify user that current password is invalid
```

At first I thought it would be good that I log in the system only for first scenario. (in this example in second scenario I already would be logged in).
But as I saw it's not good approach. So I open and close browser for each scenario using the code:

```java
@Before
public void beforeScenario(){
  driver.get("https://example.com");
}

@after
public void afterScenario(){
  driver.close();
}
```

That's OK for me. But I don't want to create WebDriver for each scenario and I don't want to initialize my POM objects for each scenario.

Now my Before method looks like it:

```java
WebDriver driver;
HomePage home;
LoginPage login;
RegistrationPage reg;

@Before
public void beforeScenario(){
  driver = new ChromeDriver();
  home = new HomePage();
  login = new LoginPage();
  reg = new RegistrationPage();
}
```

I want to initialize these objects before steps are run and use them in every step.

I research and found out that cucumber-JVM doesn't support @beforeAll hook.

Also I don't want to do some manipulation like:

```java
if( firstTime) {
  //initialise everythin
  firstTime = false
} else {
  //do nothing
}
```

How can I achieve that? Where can I initialize everything I want before my tests start?

Comment: You shouldn't have to do this, Cucumber and its integration with Selenium should handle this. (note: I only Cuke in Ruby, so I'm not certain about this, but this has been a core part of cuking in Ruby for years so I expect it applies to Java)

Comment: @diabolist Hi. for example I want this in step method  -  {   driver.get("site");  homePage.clickLogin(); } .......    But driver and homePage are not defined. I want to define them before exucting tests, I don't want to initialize them in test steps

Comment: You probably want to use `@BeforeSuite` and `@AfterSuite` for your driver close.  If you are using page factory, it's not a good idea to initialize a page object until that page is loaded, though.  Depending on the test scenario, I sometimes have to re-intialize a page object within the same test step.

Comment: @BillHileman Hi Bill. As I see BeforeSuite is from TestNG,I don't need it.I see BeforeClass of org.junit, but it doesn't work in proper way.Any other ideas?

Comment: I realized that after I posted my comment, but then I didn't see if you were using TestNG or JUnit, so I was hoping it was the former.  I use JBehave with JUnit myself, so I use the JBehave annotations `@BeforeStories`  I was surprised that Cucumber did not have its own corresponding annotations.  Perhaps consider changing to TestNG?

Comment: @BillHileman Cucumber-js has BeforeAll and AfterAll as I see,but these hooks are not supported by cucumber-jvm. Thank you for your response.I'll wait for another answers.Also I'll try testNG.thank you